# Random numer generation after static text - unique-names-generator

Tags: javascript

Soooo,
I got a little node.js script piece here.

```
const username = uniqueNamesGenerator({
  dictionaries: [
    adjectives,
    colors,
    animals,
    countries,
    names,
    languages,
    starWars
  ],
  separator: '',
  style: "capital",
  length: 3,
});
```

This generate names like `CoolSeriousBanana`,
but I want it to generate like `EXAMPLE | 8365`, but the `EXAMPLE` is everytime there and only the 4 numbers change every time.

Please help me I found nothing related to this in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/unique-names-generator
There you can find all the options available, and it looks like static text is not an option.

You could however add this static text yourself:

```
const username = 'EXAMPLE | '
  + uniqueNamesGenerator({
      dictionaries: [
        adjectives,
        colors,
        animals,
        countries,
        names,
        languages,
        starWars
      ],
      separator: '',
      style: "capital",
      length: 3,
    });
```

Comment: Thanks you so much